# Rails app cant right see the version of Ruby so I cant migrate db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake, push, migrate

Local installed Ruby 2.0.0, but app think that installed 1.9.3 version:
    `# bundle install`
`>> Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0`

```
# ruby -v
>> ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [i686-linux]
```

---

[maybe so] I get an error when try push:

`# heroku run rake db:migrate`
`>> Running rake db:migrate attached to terminal... up, run.5384`
`>> /usr/bin/env: ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory`

and local:

`# rake db:migrate` 
`>> rake aborted!` 
`>> cannot load such file -- bundler/setup`

Thank you...

Comment: Could you try deleting your Gemfile.lock? And could it be that rubygems is built against Ruby 1.9.3? If so, you might want to try reinstalling rubygems.

Comment: Have you tried to run `which ruby` and `which bundle`? Maybe you've messed up some symlinks, if you're using rbenv try to run `rbenv rehash`

Answer (score 0):

In your Gemfile add

```
ruby '2.0.0'
```